# Missing marker on google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

we have moved our own scripts to bbcode.

But on google maps there is a issue. We can't see the marker.

you can see the code here: https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-2.0/blob/master/administrator/components/com_kunena/libraries/bbcode/bbcode.php#L887

Thnx

Comment: Where can we see the problem?

Comment: srry here: http://www.kunena.org/playground/163-Feature-Playground/123674-google-maps#127667

Comment: Where is the "working" code that this came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your marker is not defined correctly. It looks like you might be expecting to see one at the geocoded result for "amsterdam".  That marker is not defined correctly (there is no map property and no position property, both of which are required).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

Replace:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    zoom: 10,
    disableDefaultUI: 0,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
```

with:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: results[0].geometry.location,
    map: kgooglemap1
    });
```

Comment: i changed it to this:

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

position: results[0].geometry.location,

map: $mapid

});

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    zoom: 10,
    disableDefaultUI: 0,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

This is all wrong.  Markers don't have any of these attributes (check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions ).  You should be doing something like:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(24.696554,-81.328238),
    map: map
});
```

Here's an article covering some of the basics of adding map markers:
http://duncan99.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/google-maps-api-adding-markers/